# When are representation rings special lambda-rings? (variations of an old question)

Tags: lambda-rings, hopf-algebras, grothendieck-rings, algebraic-k-theory, rt.representation-theory

**Status:** Questions 2 and 4 answered in the negative. Questions 1 and 3 **ARE STILL UNANSWERED**, despite previous claims.

---

On the third page of Wolfang K. Seiler's paper "lambda-rings and Adams operations in algebraic K-Theory" (pp. 93-102 in [Beilinson's Conjectures](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/get?nametype=orig&md5=71F81875DD8F2D5990771B40F64577D8)), it is claimed that the Grothendieck ring of representations of a given group $G$ over a given commutative ring $A$ modulo exact sequences is a special $\lambda$-ring. Here, "representations" means finitely-generated projective $A$-modules with a $G$-module structure. ("Special $\lambda$-ring" is what most people just call "$\lambda$-ring", as opposed to "pre-$\lambda$-ring".)

**1.** Does anybody know a proof of this? I don't understand the sketched proof in [1](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/get?nametype=orig&md5=71F81875DD8F2D5990771B40F64577D8), and I don't have the reference (R. G. Swan, *A splitting principle in algebraic $K$-theory*, in: Representation theory of finite groups and related topics, Proc. Symp. Pure Math. **21** (1971), 155-159) either. I have been told that Atiyah-Tall has a proof, but I am very skeptical about it (and if it has a proof, then I am unable to find it amid all the geometry).

I know how this is proven for the case of a characteristic $0$ field (yes, this is in Atiyah-Tall, but it is trivial using characters). My problem is to show this over arbitrary commutative rings.

**2.** What if we take the Grothendieck ring modulo split exact sequences (i. e., modulo direct sums) rather than modulo all exact sequences? Is this still a special $\lambda$-ring? What if we work over some field? What if the group is finite?

**Update on 2:** This is easily seen to be wrong, even if the field is $\mathbb F_2$ and the group is the $2$-element group. In fact, applying Krull-Schmidt and considering the Jordan decomposition of the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)$, we easily see that the $\lambda^2\left(uv\right)=\left(\lambda^1\left(u\right)\right)^2\lambda^2\left(v\right)+\left(\lambda^1\left(v\right)\right)^2\lambda^2\left(u\right)-2\lambda^2\left(u\right)\lambda^2\left(v\right)$  equation is not satisfied if both $u$ and $v$ are the representation of the $2$-element group on $\mathbb F_2^2$ in which the generator acts as $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)$.

**3.** Can we hope for any reasonable results if we replace the group by a cocommutative bialgebra? Note that cocommutativity is required to define the exterior powers of an $H$-module (where $H$ is our bialgebra). What if the bialgebra is Hopf?

**4.** What if we remove the projectivity condition on representations of $G$? I know that removing the finite-generatedness condition is a very bad idea (in fact, it makes the Grothendieck group collapse because of the [Eilenberg swindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%25E2%2580%2593Mazur_swindle#Eilenberg_swindle)), but I have seen nobody talking about the Grothendieck group of finitely generated but not-necessarily-projective modules. Is it that embarrassingly stupid?

**Update on 4:** Question 4 has now been answered by Ben Wieland in the comments to this post.

Oh, and I have already asked this question over the "field" $\mathbb F_1$. [The answer is "no" to all three questions in this case.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14324/is-the-burnside-ring-a-lambda-ring-conjecture-in-knutson-p-113) But I am interested in "real" rings and fields this time.

**EDIT:** I **might** be understanding what Seiler is doing in [1](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/get?nametype=orig&md5=71F81875DD8F2D5990771B40F64577D8), but in this case, he is doing it wrong, so I think I am not understanding him.

If I am understanding him right, Seiler's somewhat cryptic formulation "where the module induced by $M$ itself has a one-dimensional quotient, given by the linear functions on $S\left(M\right)$" means that we consider the surjection $M\otimes S\left(M\right) \to S\left(M\right)$ which sends $m\otimes m_1m_2...m_k$ to $mm_1m_2...m_k$, and its kernel is then a projective $S\left(M\right)$-module with $\lambda$-dimension one less than that of $M\otimes S\left(M\right)$ (because for every exact sequence $0\to U\to V\to W\to 0$ and every $k\geq 0$, we have the equality $\left[\wedge^k V\right] = \sum\limits_{i=0}^k \left[\wedge^i U \otimes \wedge^{k-i} W\right]$ in $K_0$). Unfortunately $M\otimes S\left(M\right)$ and $S\left(M\right)$ are not quite $S\left(M\right)$-modules with $G$-representations, because $G$ does not act $S\left(M\right)$-linearly on them (unless I did something wrong). Also we need a device to conclude that two projective $R$-modules $V$ and $W$ with $G$-module structure are equal in $K_0$ if and only if the corresponding $S\left(T\right)$-modules $V\otimes S\left(T\right)$ and $W\otimes S\left(T\right)$ with $G$-module structure are equal in $K_0$, where $T$ is some projective $R$-module; this looks like it should follow from the gradedness of symmetric algebras, but I don't see how (mostly because I have no idea what equality in $K_0$ actually means in terms of modules).

Comment: 4: Finitely generated but not projective (or at least perfect) modules are not closed under derived tensor product. eg, $A=k[t]/t^2$, $M=k$, then $Tor_n(M,M)=k$ for all $n$. So you have a Grothendieck group but it isn't a ring, let alone a $\lambda$-ring.

Comment: Hmm... What is derived tensor product? Why is it important?

Comment: Tensor product is not exact, so it is not defined on the equivalence classes in $K$-theory. The main motivation for derived tensor product is to make it exact. One application is that if $A$ is regular noetherian, $K$ of fg $A$-modules is a ring. A more elementary way is to say that $K$ of fg equals $K$ of projective, where the latter has a ring structure by regular tensor product. (I'm not answering the question "what?")

Comment: Ah!! This explains the focus on projectivity. One more question solved, thank you!

Comment: This is probably a dumb question: If $M$ is a projective $A$-module, and $2$ is not invertible in $A$, how do I know that $\bigwedge^2 M$ is projective?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: This is probably a smart question. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422826/symmetric-and-exterior-powers-of-a-projective-flat-module-are-projective-flat .

Comment: Thanks! To repeat Hanno's answer there, "projective" is equivalent to "retract of a free module". $\bigwedge$ and $\mathrm{Sym}$ preserve freeness by an explicit computation, and preserve being a retract by functoriality.

Answer (score 3):

After wondering about this question, I went and looked up Swan's paper.  His argument is basically the one Seiler is trying to say; it also uses a paper by J. Burroughs: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=269719, which I have not looked at.
According to Swan, his result only applies to the case when $A$ is noetherian for technical reasons, but that the general case would be discussed more generally elsewhere.

In the case of interest, suppose $C$ is the category of $G$ representations over $A$.  Given an object $M$ of $C$, you are supposed to consider a category $C'$.  In this case, this is a category of *graded $S(M)$-modules with compatible $G$-action*; that is the objects are graded $S(M)$-modules $Q$, together with a $G$-action on $Q$ such that the action map $S(M)\otimes Q\to Q$ is $G$-equivariant; here $G$ is acting in the evident non-trivial way on $S(M)$.

Seiler's (and Swan's) map $M\otimes S(M)\to S(M)$ is a morphism in $C'$, so you get a splitting relation of the form $[K]+[S(M)]=[M\otimes S(M)]$ in $K_0(C')$.

Swan then has an argument that the map $K_0(C)\to K_0(C')$, induced by tensoring up, is injective.  I find it hard to parse, and don't really understand it.  It involves a map  of the form
$$\theta: K_0(C')\to K_0(C)[[t]]/K_0(C)[t],$$
defined by sending $[Q]$ to $\sum [Q_k]t^k$.  (It's necessary to quotient by $K_0(C)[t]$, in order to get something that takes exact sequences to sums.)  The composite of $\theta$ with $K_0(C)\to K_0(C')$ is then shown to be injective, somehow using the fact that $\sum [S^n(M)]t^n$ has a multiplicative inverse in $K_0(C')$.

Comment: Thanks. The "compatible $G$-action" thing is what I was having troubles with; Seiler loses no words about it, so I assumed he thought it would be the trivial action. I hope that this compatible $G$-action does not interfer with taking exterior powers and tensor products.