# Exterior and symmetric  powers of external tensor products of representations    

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let us assume that $\pi: G\to Aut(V)$  and $\rho : K\to Aut(W)$ are two finite-dimensional representations of two Lie groups $G$ and $K$, and   consider the representation
  $\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho : G\times K\to  Aut(V\otimes W)$, the so called **external tensor product** of $\pi$ and $\rho$, given by

$$
(\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho)(g, k)(v\otimes  w):= \pi(g)v\otimes \rho(k)w,
$$

for any $g\in G$, $k\in K$, $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. For the second exterior power of the representation  $\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho$ is known the following 
isomorphism:

$$
\Lambda^{2}(\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho)=(\Lambda^{2}\pi \  \hat{\otimes}\ Sym^{2}\rho) \ \oplus  (Sym^{2}\pi \ \hat{\otimes} \ \Lambda^{2}\rho).
$$
Similarly, for the second symmetric power it holds that

$$
Sym^{2}(\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho)=(Sym^{2}\pi \  \hat{\otimes}\ Sym^{2}\rho) \ \oplus  (\Lambda^{2}\pi \ \hat{\otimes} \ \Lambda^{2}\rho).
$$

I would like to understand  how these formulas can be  generalized for exterior and symmetric powers of bigger degree.  For example, what we can say about

$$
\Lambda^{3}(\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho), \ \Lambda^{4}(\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho),  \ Sym^{3}(\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho), \ Sym^{4}(\pi\hat{\otimes}\rho), \ \dots \ ?
$$

For the isomorphisms above, you can see for example the link

[An isomorphism of 2-Schur modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77948/an-isomorphism-of-2-schur-modules)

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can say much. Determining these relationships boils down to determining some symmetric function identities (by looking at characters), and I don't expect there to be nice corresponding identities in general. 

Comment: why is this in CW mode?

Answer (score 11):

One has
$$
Sym^k(\pi\otimes\rho) = \bigoplus_{|\alpha|=k} \Sigma^\alpha(\pi)\otimes\Sigma^\alpha(\rho),
$$
the sum is over all Young diagrams with $k$ boxes, $\Sigma^\alpha$ is the Schur functor. Similarly,
$$
\Lambda^k(\pi\otimes\rho) = \bigoplus_{|\alpha|=k} \Sigma^\alpha(\pi)\otimes\Sigma^{\alpha^T}(\rho),
$$
where $\alpha^T$ is the transposed diagram.

Comment: Is there a convenient reference for it? And maybe divided powers version in finite characteristic?

Comment: I learned this from Kapranov's papers, and if I remember right he referred to the book of Barut and Ronchka. But I guess you can find this in many places. For example I would try Weyman's book (Cohomology of vector bundles and syzygies). 

In finite characteristic I don't know the answer (why don't you ask this as a question?), but definitely you have to be more careful. 

Comment: Apparently, if we don't insist on direct sums but are OK with a filtration, then it also works in finite characteristic as well (except that the second factor in the formula for $\Lambda$ is "the other $\Sigma$ which generalizes divided powers).

This is explained in Theorem 2.3.2 of Weyman's book. 